# Sending data to the server from one field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

There is a form in which this field

```
<input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "fio">
```

i need to send a separate name, surname, lastname. 
json: name: 'username', surname: 'usersurname', lastname: 'userlastname'
Can you tell me how to do it? With separate fields for first name, surname its clear, we can name:

```
$ ('# name'). val (), 
surname: $ ('# surname'). val (), 
lastname: $ ('# lastname'). val (),
```

but as from one field to send data?

Comment: not able to understand the question. could u explain it in a different way.

Comment: [Spli](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) use can use. You will get arrary then you can decide value of `first` to `last` name.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="text" id="fio" />
 <input type="text" id="lastname" />

function SendData() {
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '@Url.Action("Names")',
      data: { surname : $("#fio").val() },
      success: function (data) {
         // do something
       }
    });
  }

  public ActionResult Names(string surname)
  {
     // do something
  }
```

Comment: thank you, but i have only one field <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "fio">. and must send separate name lastname to server from this field

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send more data to the server, then add them into the data section in the ajax call answered by [Dean.DePue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30649473/4351257) above.

```
function sendData(name, lastName, firstName) {
  ...
  data: {
    name: name,
    lastName: lastName,
    firstName: firstName
  }
  ...
}
```